# Ember delete records in hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js

In ember, there is a fairly straightforward way to create and persist records in a hasMany relationship:

```
this.get('parent').createRecord({...});          // creates a child
this.get('parent').createRecord({...});          // creates a second child

this.get('parent').save().then(function(parent){ // persists parent
    parent.get('children').save();               // persists all children
});
```

If we inspect our network traffic, we will see two POST requests--one for each:

```
PATCH localhost:3000/parent/123
POST  localhost:3000/children/
POST  localhost:3000/children/
```

However, there is no equivalent way to do the same for DELETE. Let's say we marked a child model for deletion by clicking a button:

```
deleteChild: function(child) {
    // isDeleted -> false
    child.deleteRecord();
    // isDeleted -> true
}
```

We can immediately say `child.save()`, which will fire a `DELETE localhost:3000/children/1`, but if I want to persist them all in bulk later as before (`parent.get('children').save();`), then the following will occur:

```
PATCH localhost:3000/parent/123
PATCH  localhost:3000/children/2
```

No DELETE is sent, so when I reload the page, the record comes back. The same problem occurs if I do `parent.get('children').removeObject(child)`.

It seems to me that there should be an equivalent for the parent's `createRecord` like this:

```
this.get('parent').deleteRecord(child);
```

But no such functionality exists.

*Note: I'm using ember 1.13, ember data 1.13, and the JSONAPIAdapter/Serializer*

**Update 2:** [Looks like they fixed this in ember data 2](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/09/02/ember-data-2-0-released.html#toc_unsaved-deleted-records)

**Update:** The following code more or less simulates the desired functionality:

```
this.get('parent').save().then(function(parent){
  parent.get('children').save().then(function(children){
    children.canonicalState.forEach(function(child){
      if(child.isDeleted()){
        child.save();
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

There is some redundant list parsing but it produces the correct request for each record. Note that the canonicalState does not know about new records.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.get('parent').deleteRecord(child);
```

and sending `DELETE` request is basically:

```
child.destroyRecord();
```

[Which is part of Model API.](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_destroyRecord) It sends `DELETE` request immediately.

If you want to bulk delete records later then prepare your backend for JSONAPI and implement handling `PATCH` request as [it is part of how JSONAPI works.](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-resource-relationships)

Comment: The problem is that bulk operations are _not_ supported by JSONAPI, as they fall under the [unsupported bulk extension](http://jsonapi.org/extensions/bulk/), and therefore not as part of the JSONAPIAdapter (as far as I can tell, there is hardly any documentation around it).

As for your initial statement, I don't want destroyRecord-- I'm trying to only mark for deletion, which is what deleteRecord does. I could try to delete the relationship via the corresponding DELETE endpoint, but the issue of actually deleting the resources still exists. Even then I'm not sure the adapter supports this.

Comment: Then I would compare relationships from `PATCH` request and database and see which records should I delete in my backend.

Comment: That seems like misappropriating the jsonapi spec in a way a client (server implementer) probably wouldn't expect. I've provided a partial solution above that more or less fits the idioms defined by Ember. Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: Well, you send `DELETE` request for each record, I doubt if it's bulk delete, but if it fits your needs then good luck.